# How is NullPointerException implemented?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Checking if reference is null every time it is used wouldn't be efficient enough... I suppose real implementation uses memory protection mechanisms to detect it. Can anyone explain in detail how does it actually work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Comment: I could say by reading JVM doc: they could use ifnull conditional to check if is null and throw the exception. But no idea. (i found this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the implementation depends on the platform on which the Java Runtime Environment is running.  On some underlying platforms, 0 is a legal address, so references would need to be checked each time; on others, memory protection mechanisms might be used, though ultimately those mechanisms still involve checking the reference.

Comment: But handling an interrupt caused by memory protection is faster than checking the reference every time.

Comment: It only takes one machine instruction to check the reference, which is necessarily already in a processor register if you are about to use it.

Comment: +1. Also remember that,  in many cases, the compiler can determine statically whether a null is possible or not and discard unnecessary tests. (I don't know whether JAVAC does so, but I'm sure the JIT must.)